# How to call a User Defined function and get return value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need to get return value from a Used defined function (in a aspx.cs page) and a field (TextBox value) from a form .aspx inside a .js file and compare this two variables in a jquery function. I'm facing problem to get the values (one from a public function and another from the aspx form) inside the .js file.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, and explain how it's not doing what you want.

Comment: Resuming, I need get and compare/validate values, from .aspx page and a function, using jquery.

Comment: Yes, you stated that in the question. Please make an attempt or show what you have so far, so that we're not starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The problem was to validate a form using jquery (validate.js)
I used a hidden field to store the random value, used by the Captcha function, after, in the validateForm.js file, I get the values from the hidden field and the textbox (from the .aspx page) to make the validation using jquery (function equalTo)

Problem:
1 - Who to get, inside a .js file (separated file), the form parameters to validate/compare
Field 1: A random value, used in a Captcha funtion
Field 2: A textbox value, from a .aspx form

Aspx form

Field1:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenCaptcha" runat="server" />
```

Field 2:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtImageCaptcha" runat="server" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>
```

validationForm.js file

```
txtImageCaptcha: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                equalTo: "#HiddenCaptcha"
            }
```